# Can I use a .settings file for my Ubuntu Touch application?

Tags: application-development, bluetooth, ubuntu-touch

Can I use a .settings file for my Ubuntu Touch application? Or isn't that allowed? If yes, where should I store it? I'm developing an app that creates files for usage in my app. Should I use XML for that? What should I use? I'd also like users to exchange those created files with other users that have the same app (via bluetooth or the net). Is that possible yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the near future the SDK will provide a GSettings backend to store your application's settings.

Until then, I'd recommend using the [LocalStorage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qmlmodule-qtquick-localstorage2-qtquick-localstorage-2.html) module to store your settings in a database.

You can see an [example of how the calculator core app uses LocalStorage](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-calculator-dev/ubuntu-calculator-app/trunk/view/head:/Storage.qml).